# Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation perturbation stability

Tags: non-linear-schroedinger

Consider the nonlinear Schrödinger equation

$i\frac{\partial A}{\partial z} -\frac{\beta_2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial T^2}+\gamma|A|^2A=0$

This has steady state solution $A(z,T)=\sqrt{P_0}\exp\left(i\gamma P_0 z\right)$.

The stability of this solution is tested by including a weak perturbation to the modulus of $A$, by writing $A(z,T)=\left(\sqrt{P_0}+\epsilon(z,T)\right)\exp\left(i\gamma P_0 z\right)$.

Plugging back in the equation we get the dynamics of $\epsilon$ given by

$i\frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial z} -\frac{\beta_2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 \epsilon}{\partial T^2}+\gamma P_0\left(\epsilon + \epsilon^*\right)=0$.

What is the effect of the last term?

Comment: What do you mean by "effect"? Unless you give a specific physical interpretation for $A$ and $\epsilon$, I don't see what we could say to that.

Comment: By effect I mean what does this term do to the dynamics? This shows up in the context of lossless propagation of a quasi monochromatic light field. $A$ is the slow varying amplitude envelope and $\epsilon$ is a weak perturbation to the steady state solution. The first term comes from the self modulation and the second term comes from the dispersion in groupd velocity. What does the third term represent?

Comment: @TMG: I'm confused by your term numbers here... The first term, i.e., $i\partial \epsilon / \partial z$ doesn't account for self-phase modulation, but accounts for translation in the $z$ direction. The second term accounts for 2nd order dispersion, and the third term then accounts for a self-modulation effect on the perturbation as it is dependent on the peak power (stochastically, usually). If, however, you mean the $\epsilon^{*}$ term as the third term, look up a nonlinear effect called modulation instability and compare it with your thought process above.